# ROS publishers & subscribers still transmitting data after roscore closed

Tags: ros, roscore, transmission, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am working on a scale city project where we will have some cars running along a track connected to a watchtower. We have decided to use ROS for the project and are running Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04 on RPi 3 B+'s. Today we were testing how ROS behaves in the event of internet failure and are a bit stumped:

We have one node on a Pi publishing sensor data. On my laptop, I am running roscore and subscribing to said data.
On the pi, we set:
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://(my computer's name).local:11311/
ROS_IP=(hostname -I)

We then launch roscore on my system. Then, we run the simple publishing script on the RPi (very, very simple -- similar to the publisher example code). Next, I run the subscriber on my computer. Data is printed as expected. However -- when I kill roscore, the data keeps transmitting and printing. If I reboot roscore, it continues to transmit.

This is extremely convenient for us, but why exactly is this happening? Shouldn't I expect connection between the two machines to cease once roscore has closed?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329385/ros-publishers-&-subscribers-still-transmitting-data-after-roscore-closed/) by [ratelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/44314/ratelle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-07-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know the subscriber and publisher nodes only communicate with roscore when declaring that they are subscribing or publishing a certain topic, service, parameter etc... After that, the nodes communicate with each other directly.

You can think of roscore as a sort of DNS. Once the nodes have discovered each other, they don't need to talk to roscore any more.

You can easily verify this behavior by opening 3 terminals. On the first one you run `roscore`, on the second one you run `rostopic pub /my_int std_msgs/Int32 "data: 42" -r 1` (this will publish an integer with value 42 every second on a topic named /my_int) and on the third terminal run `rostopic echo /my_int`.

You will see the following output on the third terminal:

```
data: 42
---
data: 42
---
data: 42
---
```

After that, if you kill `roscore` on the first terminal you will see that the publisher and the subscriber are unaffected and messages data: 42 will keep piling up on the third terminal.

The problem is if roscore dies and a new node wants to register itself as a publisher or as a subscriber it will not be able to and will give you an error.

For your application you might be interested in looking into ROS2. No roscore is needed any more.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2019-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-28**:
What the OP decribes would seem to come down to an misunderstanding of how TCPROS works: it's not like MQTT where the broker is always needed. Nodes communicate peer-to-peer as soon as the initial connection has been setup, as exemplified by the series of commands shown by @Martin Peris.